# Dart-polymer build error from package "smoke"

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I'm building an application using Angular and Polymer in Dart.  Everything was going fine until I reinstalled my computer (happens some times), then I started getting this error:

> Error in pubspec for package "smoke" loaded from /Users/bruce/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/smoke-0.1.0-pre.2/pubspec.yaml:
>   "transformers.smoke/src/default_transformer" field cannot contain reserved field "$include".

Does anybody have an idea why?

Here is pubspec.yaml:

```
name: shiloh_full_app
version: 0.1.0
author: Bruce Flett Jr.
description: A sample application
homepage: shilohcoconutoil.com/admin
dependencies:
  angular: any
  angular_node_bind: any
  bootjack: any
  http_server: any
  lawndart: any
  logging: any
  polymer: any
  unittest: any
```

Comment: Hard to say. I got errors from smoke when expressions in markup reference fields that don't exist.

Comment: I'll check.  Just seems weird because it was working then it just stopped when I reinstalled.

Comment: Did you check the output of `pub upgrade`? Maybe some weird package version was downloaded? There were a few cases recently which resulted in unexpected old versions because one package had a dependency version constraint that couldn't be resolved in a way that all other packages are satisfied.